# setup Apache virtualhost on port 8888

Tags: apache, mamp, virtualhost, lumen

So I've been creating some websites using plain php on my computer and access them trough apache's virtualhost on port 80. However, now I'm working for a new company which develops microservices using lumen, so I had to install Valet to acces this local lumen projects. Valet works on port 80, so I've configured MAMP to run on the default ports [8888 and 8889 for MySQL]. ATM I can reach lumen microservices and localhost on `localhost:8888` but I can't seem to reach all my old virtualhosts.

this is the config I have right now:

httpd.conf
`Listen 8888`

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:8888
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    DocumentRoot /Volumes/User/Docs/PHP/htdocs
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ServerName lab
    # ServerAlias *.lab *.test
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Volumes/User/Docs/Workspace/sites/%1"
     <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Where is your `*:80` configuration? I'm going to wildly assume, you just removed it.